# jQuery find an sub element multiple levels down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have:

```
<div id="d1">
<label>title</label>
 <div class="col">
  <select id="location.state.id">...</select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Basically, i want to disable/enable the `<select>`. And I have something like:

```
$("#d1").find("#location.state.id").prop("disabled", true);
```

It doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: disabled is an attribute of the select element.

Comment: `$("#location\\.state\\.id")` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/575199

Comment: Putting dots in IDs is an incredibly bad idea. It's legal, but CSS uses dot for other things, so it means you have to do complicated things to reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `id` attribute has a value with `.` inside it.

Since `.` a CSS selector for class names, jQuery will look for an item that has an ID `location` and the CSS classes `state` and `id`, instead of an element with the ID `location.state.id`.

You must use the `\\`  before the `.` to use them in a query selector (in CSS, only `\` would be good):

```
$('#d1').find('location\\.state\\.id').prop('disabled', true);
```

---

**Quoting [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

> To use any of the meta-characters (such as 
>   ``` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^``{|}~ ```) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with
>   `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

If you want to escape special characters use \. In your case:

```
$("#d1").find("#location\\.state\\.id").prop("disabled", true);
```